# Request Size Limit and Response Size Limit for tiny proxy

Tags: proxy, tinyproxy

Request Size Limit and Response Size Limit for tiny proxy

we have configured tinyproxy server as a proxy for our service we need to know the Request Size Limit and Response Size Limit for tiny proxy. We have checked the official documentations we cannot find the limit.